# How to check if a specific field was sent on sequelize's hooks?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using a beforeUpdate hook on my User model to hash the password when its changed. But its changing the password whenever any field is sent. How can I check if the password was sent before return the hooks function?

I tried to place the return inside a `if(user.password !== '')`. But its doesn't work, probably because its referring to the stored password.

Here is my code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const connection = require('../../../db/connection.js')

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const User = connection.define('user', {
  fullName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    validate: { isEmail: true }
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
})

// Create hash for password, on before create, using bcrypt
User.beforeCreate((user, options) => {
  return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(hash => {
    user.password = hash
  })
})

// Create hash for password, on before update, using bcrypt
User.beforeUpdate((user, options) => {
  return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(hash => {
    user.password = hash
  })
})

module.exports = User
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be using `afterValidate` hook in your model definition as shown below -

```
// Create hash for password, on before create/update, using bcrypt
User.afterValidate((user) => {
  user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password,10);
})
```

The sequence in which hooks are called -

```
(1)
  beforeBulkCreate(instances, options)
  beforeBulkDestroy(options)
  beforeBulkUpdate(options)
(2)
  beforeValidate(instance, options)

[... validation happens ...]

(3)
  afterValidate(instance, options)
  validationFailed(instance, options, error)
(4)
  beforeCreate(instance, options)
  beforeDestroy(instance, options)
  beforeUpdate(instance, options)
  beforeSave(instance, options)
  beforeUpsert(values, options)

[... creation/update/destruction happens ...]

(5)
  afterCreate(instance, options)
  afterDestroy(instance, options)
  afterUpdate(instance, options)
  afterSave(instance, options)
  afterUpsert(created, options)
(6)
  afterBulkCreate(instances, options)
  afterBulkDestroy(options)
  afterBulkUpdate(options)
```

More details [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html)

Comment: If the password isn't updated, wouldn't this end up hashing the previous password hash again?

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this :

```
User.beforeCreate((user, options) => {
    // user.password // Will check if field is there or not
    // user.password != "" // check if empty or not
    user.password = user.password && user.password != "" ? bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10) : "";
})
```

Comment: Didn't you mean User.beforeUpdate? I tested it, and it doesn't work either. The password is still changing when its is not sent on PUT. I think its because user.password is referring to the already stored password, and its always returns true. So what it does is create a hash of a hash.